# Entity Framework Code First - Adding 1:many through aggregate root

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design, ef-code-first, poco

I have a question regarding adding children to a root entity in Entity Framework 4.1 CF.

Considering the following infrastructure Entity base class and two POCOs:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TKeyDataType>
{
    [Key]
    public TKeyDataType Id { get; set; }

    // Equality methods ommitted for brevity...
}

public class Foo : EntityBase<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FooSibling> Siblings { get; set; }
}

public class FooSibling : EntityBase<int>
{
    public string SiblingPropFoo { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that `Foo` implements `IAggregateRoot` (just an empty interface - think of it as metadata in the "data about data" context).

So far, so good. If I run this, EF creates the database with the appropriate 1:many relationship.

The only fluent mapping I have on these two entities are:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Siblings)
            .WithRequired(x=>x.Foo)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

No `FooSibling` without a `Foo`.  Blow away a `Foo`, you blow away all its sibling.  This piece works.

The issue is when adding FooSiblings POCO to the Foo POCO, I have to use unique negative numbers as shown in this service method:

```
public ResponseBase UpdateBy(RequestBase<Foo> request)
{
    ResponseBase response = new ResponseBase();
    try
    {
        Foo foo = FooRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.Entity.Id);

        // Dummy adds to test associations.  
        // These come back on the Foo inside the request, but I'm explicitly putting them here  
        // for the purpose of this question. 

        request.Entity.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Id = -2, SiblingPropFoo = "Prop1",  SiblingPropFoo2 = "Prop2" });
        request.Entity.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Id = -1, SiblingPropFoo = "Prop1", SiblingPropFoo2 = "Prop2" });

        // Update Foo's scalars and children (mapping is Foo->Foo)
        foo = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(request.Entity, foo);

        UnitOfWork.Commit();
        response.Success = true; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = e.Message; 
    }
    return response;
}
```

Once the `UnitofWork.Commit()` is called (it just calls `SaveChanges` of the context - no magic here), all is well...

However, if I don't use unique negative numbers like and just try to set its parent, like this:

```
request.Entity.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo, SiblingPropFoo = "Prop1",  SiblingPropFoo2 = "Prop2" });
request.Entity.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo, SiblingPropFoo = "Prop1", SiblingPropFoo2 = "Prop2" });
```

Only one gets persisted to the database.

The only other way I know of to do it without using negative numbers is to use the FooSiblings DbSet directly in the service method:

```
IRepository<FooSibling> siblingRepo = new CookieCutterEntityFrameworkRepository<FooSibling>(UnitOfWork);
siblingRepo.Insert(new FooSibling() { FooId = foo, .... });
```

My CookieCutter repository is abstracting all the DbSet stuff, etc.

But ... stripping off all the abstraction and generic voodoo for clarity, the question really comes down to is there a way to update my Foo POCO (the root Entity) and add new siblings through one DbSet without using negative numbers?

For reference (without abstraction using pure DbContext):

```
// This works (using multiple DbSets/Repositories always make life easier...) 
Ctx.Foos.Update(foo);  
Ctx.FooSiblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo, ... }); 
Ctx.FooSiblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo, ... }); 
Ctx.SaveChanges();  

// This works too (using negative number trick - foo scalar properties get 
// updated and the siblings get persisted to the database properly).  
foo.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Id = -2, ....});
foo.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Id = -1, ....});
Ctx.Foos.Update(foo);  
Ctx.SaveChanges();  

// This doesn't work (but it's what I'm striving for to drive everything off the root).
foo.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo });
foo.Siblings.Add(new FooSibling() { Foo = foo });
Ctx.Foos.Update(foo);  
Ctx.SaveChanges();
```

In the last case (the non-working case), I'm striving to configure it in a fashion where it picks up any changes to the Foo POCO itself.

I've tried with Proxies turned off and on.  Also, in the way this is setup, the context remains in scope for the life of the entire HTTP request.

If not possible, what suggestion(s) would you give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, the problem is expected via dbcontext or objectcontext.

FIrst I want to look at your last set of examples ..no abstraction. When you attach a graph to a context, everything in the graph is attached as Unchanged. Period. The context doesn't care how you added or attached "children" to the root (e.g. siblings to a foo) before the context had ANY knowledge of them. If the foo was aalready known by the context and THEN you ADD, then the context is aware of HOW you did the linking..you said "ADD" so it marks them as Added and they'll get inserted.Even if the root is not new. You'ld have to change its state to "Unchanged". But in your case, you are taking a disconnected graph and attaching it, so everyting in the graph is seen as unchanged. You have to explicitly change the state of each of the siblings to what you want for SaveChanges to notice it needs to INSERT.

Now to your repository. I have no idea wtf is up with the negative numbers. :) And I don't have time to experiment with that. (curious how that's tricking savechanges, but it's a smelly hack :) ) It depends on what's happening behind your FooRepository query. If that returned foo is beingi tracked by the context, then I would *expect* that when you ADD siblings, the context will know they are added and will create an insert. But if it is not being tracked, then when you ADD the siblings, context is not there to know about "ADD". At whatever point you reattach the graph (foo + its siblings) to a context, they are all going to be "UNchanged" so you're not getting the desired insert.

This is all dependent on a GUESS at whatever else is going on in your repository and what, if any, affect the automapper has. I am guessing that you are doing all of the owrk before the context is aware of the graph so in the end , I think you're calling ATTACH which would result in no INSERTS being sent to the db.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Julie.  The problem was actually on my EntityBase object.  I overrode the GetHashCode method and was returning the HashCode on the ID itself...so the Hashcode of 0 is always equal.  Once I commented that out, everything is firing together through the root.  I agree 100% the negative numbers is a bit hackish.